# WEBRTC : Adding stun/turn server configuration after RtcPeerConnection creation

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Hi i have a problem while i am implementing trickle ice. We decided to wait just for host candidates while sending to initial offer because of c line 0.0.0.0 ip issue. But how can we do it i couldnt find any event that " this types of candidates was finished so starting next types gatherings" . so we decided to

- create a peer object but no stun /turn config
- take host candidates ( waiting for the end because of no stun / turn config )
- the. send initial offer
- adding stun turn server config
- and then we sent to new type of (reflexive or relay) candidates to server.

But we couldnt find how to add stun turn server config to existing object . In the firefox docs "Events such as adding a new interface or a new TURN server will cause the state to go back to gathering." but we couldnt find

Any different approach to that problem would be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding TURN servers during peerconnection lifetime is done via http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#widl-RTCPeerConnection-setConfiguration-void-RTCConfiguration-configuration -- but afaik neither Chrome nor Firefox implement that yet.